# Spring Data JPA - One to One Relationship not fetching dependent objects

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading

I have defined a one to One relationship between my objects. I have set

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

I am using CrudRepository to read the values of one the classes. However I don't want the dependent object to retrieved unless I fetch it explicitly. In the below example I don't want Order to be retrieved when I fetch customer. I guess this run an additional query in the background to fetch order details , which I want to avoid.

```
public Customer{

private String id;
private String fname;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Order order;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to the annotation

resulting in

`@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`